# My code does not work on Release mode while works on Debug mode in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

I have signal/slot code. I want function on another class to work when checkbox is being toggled. I wrote the following code. Signal/Slot is working properly on Debug mode. However, it does not work on Release mode.

I also want my program to works dynamically. I do not need to open a new window.

Here is my code. Thank you in advance.

**preferences.cpp**

```
Projects *projects;
// projects = new Projects; // I dont want to create new one. I just want to make changes on the existing Mainwindow (Projects class)

connect(ui->checkBox_toolbar, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), projects, SLOT(hide_toolbar(bool)));
connect(ui->checkBox_button, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), projects, SLOT(hide_buttons(bool)));
```

**projects.cpp**

```
void Projects::hide_toolbar(bool checked)
{
    ui->toolBar->setVisible(checked);
}
```

I have got warning:  **'projects' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized] connect(ui->checkBox_toolbar, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), projects, SLOT(hide_toolbar(bool)));**

And error: **"QObject::connect: Cannot connect QCheckBox::toggled(bool) to (null)::hide_toolbar(bool)"**

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What "does not work" mean exactly ?
Also, please use pointer syntax to make connections, it helps finding errors: `connect(ui->checkBox_toolbar, &QCheckbox::toggled, projects, &Projects::hide_toolbar);`

Comment: A program that works in debugging mode but fails in release mode is often caused by a bad operation on a pointer (dereferencing a null, falling off the end of an array, using an uninitialised pointer, etc etc).    The code you have provided doesn't provide any useful information about the cause - the best you can hope for without a [mcve] is general advice (like I've given) or guesswork (about behaviour of code you haven't shown).

Comment: signal/slot does not work properly on Release mode. I have got error: "QObject::connect: Cannot connect QCheckBox::toggled(bool) to (null)::hide_toolbar(bool)"

Comment: And I have this warning: 'projects' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     connect(ui->checkBox_toolbar, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), projects, SLOT(hide_toolbar(bool)));

Comment: You have an empty pointer to Projects, not an object with proper SLOT to connect.

Comment: Well, projects is a local variable and is uninitialized, so yeah... Initialize it to point to right object?

Comment: Usually, errors in release mode but not in debug mode are caused by uninitialized variables, including pointers.  Many debuggers will initialize variables for you, but release mode doesn't.

Comment: Also, if you see nothing strange about defining an variable, not initializing it, and then using it, I suggest you brush up on C++ basics like pointers and variable lifetime etc (just note that C++ is a vast language so what is "basics" is matter of opinion, and most of the newer std:: stuff isn't very relevant to utilizing Qt).

Comment: When I write "projects = new Projects;" to initialize, how can I make changes on existing "Projects"?

Comment: @redrussianarmy read about passing pointers to functions

Comment: I just want to make changes on the current Mainwindow (Projects). I dont want to open new Mainwindow. When I click on checkbox in Dialog, Mainwindow at back should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your interest.

I handled with the following code:

```
Projects *projects = qobject_cast<Projects *>(parent);
```

Answer (score 2):

The warning tells you exactly what is wrong. The `projects` pointer variable is uninitialized. It does not point to a valid `Projects` object. You cannot use it like that, that’s undefined behaviour. That it seems to work in debug mode is pure coincidence.

Your commented out code says something about the existing main window. If you want to connect to a slot of that main window, you need to get a pointer to that main window object first. Then you can connect.

Comment: Then how should I rewrite the code? Could you please give me an example on code?

Comment: I can’t. From your code snippet it is not apparent how you could acquire a pointer to the existing main window object.